# Middleman Blog post with multiple categories

Tags: middleman

My Front Matter has the following Categories & Tags.

category:

- catA

- catB

- catC

tags:

- tagA

- tagB

- tagC

Middleman-Blog creates three separate folders for each tag under "Tags" folder. While expecting the same functionality for "**category**", it generates one folder named **catA-catB-catC**.

How do I generate three folders instead?

Comment: Can you please share your Middleman config? Use http://gist.github.com/ to share the whole thing and/or post the relevant parts directly into your question. Don't forget to write a follow-up comment, so that i notice.

Comment: I posted the same question over Github and it was closed by declaring "categories" are not meant to be as above. :)) FAIL.